# Register on Dokuwiki on Ubuntu Server in VirtualBox

Tags: dokuwiki

We bought a product but the company stopped any support services, because it got bought by Google....

The only thing we are left with is an image of their Ubuntu 14.04 server with a Dokuwiki and svn-service installed. I can not log on to the server though.

I can start the server in virtualbox and with the network option "host-only-adapter" I can access the front page of the wiki, via ip/wiki.
Somehow the login they provided us with doesn't work!!!
So now I want to register a new account, but the server in the VM struggles to send an E-Mail. 
I get the error:

> "Looks like there was an error on sending the password mail. Please
>   contact the admin!"

A search for this error gives me:

> When using DokuWiki's ACL feature, it uses PHP's mail function to send
>   the password email. You will get this error when that call fails. This
>   usually means the 'sendmail' command is not available, and you need to
>   install sendmail or some other MTA which mimics the sendmail command.
>   On Unix systems this should work out of the box, on Windows systems
>   you will need to configure the access to your MTA in the php.ini.

Do you have an idea how I could enable the E-Mail service within the wiki to send me a Email, so I could register? Any other ideas how to solve this mess, would be appreciated as well!

Comment: Is this image a previously configured and functional copy of the product?  Or, is it a "new installation"?

Comment: Good question, I assume it is a new installation, but I"m not sure.